# Make an OS X install that boots in single user mode by default

Tags: macos, boot

I'd like to make a bootable OS X on a USB stick for the purpose of running some maintenance scripts.

Ideally, I'd like it to appear as an option when I start the machine with the Option key held down, and when I choose to boot from there, I'd like it to start up in Single User mode (or to the console in some form or other) automatically, so I can then run any of the maintenance scripts that I have added to that volume.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

While booted into your USB OS X, open a terminal and type the command:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="-s"
```

You won't be presented with an option, but it will automatically boot directly into single-user mode.

Comment: Won't that make the computer boot everything in Single User mode until I change it back? I was hoping to have the partition boot into Single User mode on whatever system I boot it from without having to do anything to the system first to make that happen.

P.S. technically, I just want to boot to a console (no UI). Whether it's truly in "Single User" mode is probably not important.

Comment: Up-voted because this is helpful info, even if it doesn't end up being an acceptable answer.

Comment: Have a look here [link](https://macosx.com/threads/howto-boot-into-console-mode.7093/).  Changing /etc/ttys as this thread shows should do the trick

Comment: Maybe if I use the "--options" option for `bless`? That's an option that "in general should be avoided" according to the docs, but maybe this is a case where it makes sense to use it if it actually does what I'm looking for?

Comment: See the link I posted above ^

Comment: I haven't been able to try your suggestion yet. I presume that it will work, and I'll accept your answer when it does.

Comment: It turns out the /etc/ttys doesn't work anymore. Darn.